# Hangfire is running jobs sequentially

Tags: asp.net-web-api, owin, autofac, hangfire, hangfire-autofac

I am using HangFire hosted by IIS with an app pool set to "AlwaysRunning".  I am using the Autofac extension for DI.  Currently, when running background jobs with HangFire they are executing sequentially. Both jobs are similar in nature and involve File I/O.  The first job executes and starts generating the requisite file.  The second job executes and it starts executing.  It will then stop executing until the first job is complete at which point the second job is resumed.  I am not sure if this is an issue related to DI and the lifetime scope.  I tend to think not as I create everything with instance per dependency scope.  I am using owin to bootstrap hangfire and I am not passing any BackgroundServer options, nor am I applying any hints via attributes.  What would be causing the jobs to execute sequentially?  I am using the default configuration for workers.  I am sending a post request to web api and add jobs to the queue with the following `BackgroundJob.Enqueue<ExecutionWrapperContext>(c => c.ExecuteJob(job.SearchId, $"{request.User} : {request.SearchName}"));`

Thanks In Advance

Comment: How many workers do you have Hangfire configured for? How are you queuing the jobs?

Comment: I update the original question with the answer to your question

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for that exact behavior recently and I manage to have that by using this attribute..

```
[DisableConcurrentExecution(<timeout>)]
```

Might be that you had this attribute applied, either in the job or globally?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you were looking for?

```
var hangfireJobId = BackgroundJob.Enqueue<ExecutionWrapperContext>(x => x.ExecuteJob1(arguments));
hangfireJobId = BackgroundJob.ContinueWith<ExecutionWrapperContext>(hangfireJobId, x => x.ExecuteJob2(arguments));
```

This will basically execute the first part and when that is finished it will start the second part